# Creating multiple charts and selecting them later

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm working on a calendar that has a chart in each day, that should render segments differently depending on the event data in the respective cell.

Here is what my chart creation looks like. This is happening inside fullcalendar's dayRender event, so it's running this exact code for each day

```
            var theCanvas = $('canvas#'+idDate);
            var initialSegements = getTotalNumberOfSegments();
            var pieData = [];

            for(var i=0; i < initialSegements; i++){
                var o = {
                    value: 360/initialSegements,
                    color: '#fff'
                }
                pieData.push(o)
            };

            var pieOptions = {
                segmentShowStroke : true,
                segmentStrokeColor : "#dedede",
                segmentStrokeWidth : 1,
                percentageInnerCutout : 0,
                animation : true,
                animationSteps : 30,
                animationEasing : "easeOut",
                animateRotate : true,
                animateScale : true,
            }

            var ctx = theCanvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
            window.dayPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(pieData,pieOptions);
            window.dayPieChart.update();
```

But that seems like it's just setting ONE object called dayChart in the window scope. The reason I'm using window scope is because that's the only way I could even get Chartjs to work; selecting an element in the DOM and running Chartjs methods on it doesn't work, for some reason.

Each day has a canvas with a unique ID (for example, #canvas08-18-2015), so I tried selecting the canvas and running a Chartjs method on that, but no dice.

***So how can I create a unique ID for the CHART? How do I do this:***

```
window.[UNIQUE ID STORED IN VAR GOES HERE] = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data,options);
```

***and then call it later to pass .update() or some other methods?***

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Add a minimalist version of your chart code so we can better understand how to fit in what you need.

Comment: @J0e3gan Thanks! I've added a bunch more code and information, as well as what I've tried so far. I *think* the problem is just that I can't figure out how to interact with the Chart that's inside the canvas... it seems like a canvas is kind of a container and you can't get methods to pass through into the content inside? At least in the case of Chartjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But that seems like it's just setting ONE object called dayChart in
>   the window scope.

That's because you are assigning the chart instance to the same variable each time. What you probably want is

To initialize (once)

```
window.piieCharts = [];
```

and then each time you create a chart

```
window.piieCharts.push(new Chart(ctx).Pie(pieData,pieOptions));
```

and you can get the instances by index

```
window.piieCharts[0].update();
```

---

Or you can use an object. To initialize

```
window.piieCharts = {};
```

and then each time you create a chart

```
window.piieCharts['canvas#'+idDate] = new Chart(ctx).Pie(pieData,pieOptions);
```

and you can get the instances by the key

```
window.piieCharts['canvas#'+idDate].update();
```

---

Alternatively since Chart.js stores each instance it creates (till they are destroyed) in Chart.instances, you can also do

```
var myInstance;
Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function(instance) { 
    if (instance.chart.canvas === document.getElementById('canvas#'+idDate))
         myInstance = instance;
});
myInstance.update();
```

Comment: Using the object method works for rendering the charts, but I'm unable to select and edit them. I'm trying it like this:

`window.dayCharts['canvas#08-13-2015'].segments[1].color = '#ff00ff';`
`window.dayCharts['canvas#08-13-2015'].update();`

But it returns "undefined"

Comment: It's `window.dayCharts['canvas#08-13-2015'].segments[1].fillColor = '#ff00ff'`, not color

Comment: Oops! Thank you for your help!!